# Render a single item from React.children - How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a single item from React.props.children.

My usage looks like this...

```
render() {
    return (
        <DataListManager idName = "stops"
                         baseUrl={`/api/stop/${HiddenState.getAltId()}`} 
                         errorProcessor={new ErrorProcessor()}
                         emptyMessage = "No stops have been added to this service yet."
                         confirmDeleteTitleCallback={(stop) => `Delete ${stop.name}?`}
                         confirmDeleteMessageCallback={(stop) => `Do you want to delete the stop ${stop.name}? This cannot be undone.`}>
            <StopForm for="create"
                      formId="new-stop" 
                      submitText="Add stop" />
            <StopForm for="edit"
                      submitText="Update stop" />
        </DataListManager>
    );
}
```

I have 2 'StopForm' components, but I only want to render 1 of them dependent on the state of the component - The children are passed down a few layers to a toggle component that is generic for both create and edit scenarios. I want to render a different form for different scenarios.

Here is the method to render the edit view when creating a new item...

```
renderEdit(object, onCancelClickCallback, onSubmitSuccessCallback) {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
        stop: object,
        onChange: this.onChange,
        onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
        onCancel: onCancelClickCallback,
        onSubmitSuccess: onSubmitSuccessCallback
    }));

    childrenWithProps.forEach((child) => {
        if (child.props.for == "create") {
            return child;
        }
    });
}
```

(The render() method will call either renderEdit() or renderDisplay() dependent on it's state).

I can;t seem to get a single item to render however. I have tried the following variations but none have worked...

```
    childrenWithProps.forEach((child) => {
        if (child.props.for == "create") {
            return <div>{child}</div>;
        }
    });

    childrenWithProps.forEach((child) => {
        if (child.props.for == "create") {
            return {child};
        }
    });
```

Child seems to be a valid React object, yet I keep seeing this error...

**render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why do you need to pass these down as children as opposed to rendering them where your logic is?

Comment: They would be rendered in a place where the Form components specificity (which types of data they can edit and the fields for doing so) is not known as the main functionality of the data list is generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return in a `forEach` in the first place. Use `filter` or `map` to do the things you need.

```
const result = childrenWithProps.filter((child) => {
   return (child.props && child.props.for === "create");
}
return result[0] || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using `Array.prototype.filter` in the end as follows...

```
renderEdit(object, onCancelClickCallback, onSubmitSuccessCallback) {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => 
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            stop: object,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
            onCancel: onCancelClickCallback,
            onSubmitSuccess: onSubmitSuccessCallback
        })
    );

    return <div>{childrenWithProps.filter((child) => child.props.for == "create")}</div>;
}
```

So I got an array with a single item in it. This seems a bit shonky though - better answers welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Class instance method:

```
getChildComponents(children) {
    return children.length > 1 ? (
        children.map((child, index) => (
            <ChildComponent key={`child-component-${index}`}>
                {child}
            </ChildComponent>
        ))
    ) : (
        <ChildComponent>{children}</ChildComponent>
    );
}
```

Component `render` function:

```
render() {
    const children = this.props.children;
    return <div>{children && this.getChildComponents(children)}</div>;
}
```